# What is Interface.super

Tags: java

I have recently used default methods in java.
In its implementation I found

```
public interface DefaultMethod {
    default String showMyName(String name){
        return "Hai "+name;

    }
}


public class DefaultMethodMainImpl implements DefaultMethod{

    @Override
    public String showMyName(String name){
        return DefaultMethod.super.showMyName(name);

    }
}
```

My question is in **DefaultMethod.super** where **super** will call it have no super class except Object? **what super will return**?

Comment: super is an key word not an reference or object for super/parent class, it will call method or constructor of super/parent class.

Comment: interfaces can `extend` other interfaces.

Comment: Thanks you are right, But my doubt is here DefaultMethod interface have no super class, then which constructor is called?

Comment: you cant use super class then no use of super keyword in that interface/class

Comment: Thanks khAn your answer is right.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you use `super` in a `class` it usually refers to the ancestor of that class (either the `extend`ed class or `Object`).

In the case of overriden `default` method of an `interface` you have to specify the specific interface which default implementation you want to invoke, hence

```
<Interface>.super.<method>();
```

See also [The diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

Answer (score 12):

`<Interface>.<method>();` would consider `<method>` as static, and this is not the case. Hence the use of key word `super` which is a reference variable that is used to refer a "parent" object.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this code:

```
public interface One {
default void method (){
    System.out.println("method from One");
}
}

interface Two extends One {
  default void method(){
    System.out.println("method from Two");
}
}

class Three implements Two{

  public void method (){
    Two.super.method();
  }
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Three().method();
  }
}
```

`Output: method from Two`

`Two.super.method()` is just a clumsy syntax to avoid the diamond problem explained in another answer.
As you can see from the program output, `super` not really means "calling to ancestor" as it used to be in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that there could be more than one interface with a super level having a default method with the same method signature. The java compiler needs to understand what Interface is referring to here.

See the below example.

```
public interface ABC {
    default String showMyName(String name) {
        return "Hai " + name;

    }
}

public interface CDE {
    default String showMyName(String name) {
        return "Hey.........!!! " + name;

    }
}

public class DefaultMethodMainImpl implements ABC, CDE {

    @Override
    public String showMyName(String name) {
        System.out.println(ABC.super.showMyName(name));
        System.out.println(CDE.super.showMyName(name));
        return ABC.super.showMyName(name);
    }
}
```